# How can i make a plugin execute a command from another plugin?

Tags: plugins, minecraft

i need help in developing pretty simple plugin for miencraft version 1.15.2

Plugin is made to check if user has allready logged for a first time if not:
i adds him to a hashmap (so it wont check him twice) and executes a command on a player to add give him permission from plugin LuckPerms.

I've found out that there is PluginCommand:
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/PluginCommand.html
But im not quite sure how to use it to make it perform (as server):
/lp user playerName group add groupname

EDIT:
I just can't find how to execute a command so the player will get the permission.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Get luckperms or permissions ex to manage permissions

Answer (score 0):

in your use case the LuckPerms API would make sense to me.
You could use the API to set the Rank of the player loggin in.

```
LuckPerms api = LuckPermsProvider.get();
api.getUserManager().getUser(uuid).setPrimaryGroup("groupname");
```

For more info check the [Wiki](https://github.com/lucko/LuckPerms/wiki/Developer-API)